# uninitialized pointer of structure to the function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, data-structures, structure

I am trying to learn C programming, but I got stuck when I was trying to pass an uninitialized pointer of structure to the function.

This is my structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[30];
    char surname[30];
    char gender;
    char DOB[10];
    int waist;
    int hip;
}healthcare_table;
```

my main

```
int main() {
    healthcare_table *records;
    int step = 1;
    load_healthcare_table(records,&step);
    return 0;
}
```

My function will open the file and according to the number of lines in the text file, it will initialize the pointers, but I cannot do it. Any suggestion?

UPDATE:
I am taking such that error, I do not know what is wrong.
Error message is :**Exception thrown at 0x00D7529C in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000004C.**

And this is my updated code:

```html
typedef struct {
 char name[30];
 char surname[30];
 char gender;
 char DOB[10];
 int waist;
 int hip;
}healthcare_table;

void load_healthcare_table(healthcare_table **t, int *step) {
 int i;
 FILE *infile;
 infile = fopen("records.txt", "r");
 if (infile == NULL)
  printf("File not opened successfully");
 else
  printf("File opened successfully");
 for (i = 0; fscanf(infile, "%s %s %c %s %d %d", *t[*step]->name, *t[*step]->surname, t[*step]->gender, *t[*step]->DOB, t[*step]->waist, t[*step]->hip) != EOF; i++) {
  if (fgetc(infile) == '\n') {
   *step++;
   //*t = (healthcare_table*)realloc(*t, *step);
   //fprintf(infile, "%s %s %c %s %d %d", *t[*step]->name, *t[*step]->surname, t[i]->gender, *t[*step]->DOB, t[*step]->waist, t[*step]->hip);
  }
 }
 *t = (healthcare_table*)malloc((*step) * sizeof(healthcare_table));
 for (i = 0; fscanf(infile, "%s %s %c %s %d %d", *t[i]->name, *t[i]->surname, t[i]->gender, *t[i]->DOB, t[i]->waist, t[i]->hip) != EOF; i++) {
  if (fgetc(infile) == '\n')
   fprintf(infile, "%s %s %c %s %d %d", *t[i]->name, *t[i]->surname, t[i]->gender, *t[i]->DOB, t[i]->waist, t[i]->hip);
 }

}

void display_healthcare_table(healthcare_table *records) {
 
}

void search() {

}

void WHR_interpreter() {

}

int main() {
 healthcare_table *records=NULL;
 int step = 0;
  load_healthcare_table(&records, &step);
 return 0;

}
```

UPDATE 2:
I think problems are fscanf and fprintf. how can i solve the problem if I am wrong?

Comment: Start formatting this mess properly and a [mcve].

Comment: C allows wild pointers, which is a fault with the language. Ensure that all pointers are either null or that they point to valid objects in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to allocate the pointer in the main function, you have two possible solutions:

**Solution 1**

Do not pass the healthcare_table pointer to the load_healthcare_table() function, but rather return the initialized pointer from the function itself. Something along these lines:

```
int main() {
    healthcare_table *records;
    int step = 1;
    records = load_healthcare_table(&step);
    return 0;
}
```

In this case your load_healthcare_table() function would be:

```
healthcare_table* load_healthcare_table(int* step) {
    healthcare_table *table;
    table = (healthcare_table*)malloc(sizeof(healthcare_table));
    // Fill table here
    return table;
}
```

**Important note**
In this case make sure you *do not* create the table locally to the load_healthcare_table() function. This would destroy the table once the function returns, resulting in garbage data. A function should never return a pointer to its local data. So the following example would be **wrong**:

```
healthcare_table* load_healthcare_table(int* step) {
    healthcare_table table;
    // Fill table here
    return &table;
}
```

**Solution 2**

Pass a pointer to a pointer of the healthcare_table to the function load_healthcare_table(). It would look something along these lines:

```
int main() {
    healthcare_table *records;
    int step = 1;
    load_healthcare_table(&records,&step);
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, the load_healthcare_table() function will be:

```
void load_healthcare_table(healthcare_table** t, int* step ) {
    *t = (healthcare_table*)malloc(sizeof(healthcare_table));
    // Fill table here
}
```

**EDIT**

As suggested by Ajay Brahmakshatriya: Sticking to standard C notion of local variables rather than going into stack terminologies.

Comment: @BrianZammit *In this case make sure you do not create the table on the stack* The C standard doesn't say anything about a stack. I think you meant local scope.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya Correct.Yes, that would be more appropriate in terms of the C standard. However, the compiled code would (up to my knowledge) place those variables on the stack. Each function called will create its own stack frame which holds its local variables. Upon return this stack frame is "destroyed" and thus invalidated. It will be overwritten by future stack frames and thus it is incorrect for a function to return a pointer to its local variable

Comment: @BrianZammit I do not disagree with the explanation you made. But what you mention is about one implementation that uses a stack to store local variables. There could be (and are) many implementations that do not use a stack at all. Using the word stack might give a wrong idea that this problem is only for the implementations that use stack, but is actually for all.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya Thanks for the clarification. Answer was edited accordingly. I have never heard of implementations that do not use stack. Would it be possible to point me to some resources where I can study such approaches? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no use in passing an uninitialized pointer to a function, then it could be useful to pass an unallocated pointer as long as:

- the pointer has been initialized to be a null-pointer.
- the function either uses `realloc()` to reallocate memory for the pointer or check if it is a null-pointer before using `malloc()`.
- the function returns the pointer.

example code snippet (assuming the struct `a_struct` is defined):

```
a_struct *a_funct(a_struct *p);
int main(void)
{
    struct a_struct *p_a_struct = NULL;
    p_a_struct = a_funct(p_a_struct);
    return 0;
}

a_struct *a_funct(a_struct *p)
{
    // Does some stuff to find how many records p should point to.
    p = realloc(p, sizeof a_struct * number_of_records);
    // Check p for error.
    // Do more stuff?
    return p;
}
```

Or you could pass a pointer to a pointer to the function as has been mentioned in other answers.